# Greedy algorithm - minimize number of operations to complete task

Tags: algorithm, greedy

I am trying to solve a programming challenge question. For convenience, I have summarized it below:

> Given an array, A, of positive integers. In one operation, we can choose **one** of the elements in the array, A[i] and reduce it by a fixed amount X. At the same time, the rest of the elements will be reduced by a fixed amount Y. We need to find the minimum number of operations to reduce all elements to a non-positive number (i.e. 0 and below).
>
> Constraints:
> 1 <= |A| <= 1e5
> 1 <= A[i] <= 1e9
> 1 <= Y < X <= 1e9
> Time limit: 1 second
>
> [Source](http://dunjudge.me/analysis/problems/1754/)

For example, let X = 10, Y = 4 and A = {20, 20}.

The optimal approach for this example is:

Operation 1: Choose item 0.

A = {10, 16}

Operation 2: Choose item 0.

A = {0, 12}

Operation 3: Choose item 1.

A = {-4, 2}

Operation 4: Choose item 1.

A = {-8, -8}

Hence, the answer is 4.

---

My approach:

Keep choosing the **current** maximum element in the array and reduce it by X (and reduce the rest of the elements by Y). Clearly, this approach would exceed the time limit due to the possibly small values of X and Y (i.e. the number of iterations that my algorithm will perform is lower bounded by max(A[i]) / 2 ).

Could someone please advise me on a better solution?

Comment: Do all elements after the process need to be equalled? or smt like [-1, -2, -3] will be ok?

Comment: @PhamTrung They don't have to be equalled. Anything <= 0 is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem could be solved by using binary search

First, we want to check if within `a` operations, whether we can make all elements become <= 0; we could check for each element, the minimum number of operations, `b`, such that if we subtract `x` for `b` operations and subtract `y` for the remaining `a-b` operations, then the resultant value of the element will become <= 0. Sum all of those numbers together, and if the `sum <= a`, which means we could use `a` operations.

Then, we could apply binary search to search for a valid `a`.

```
int st = 0;
int ed = max element / y + 1;
int result = ed;
while(start <= end){
    int mid = (st + ed)/2;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i : A){
        sum += minTimesMinusX(i, mid);
    }
    if(sum <= mid){
        result = mid;
        ed = mid - 1;
    }else{
        st = mid + 1;
    }
}
return result;
```

Time complexity `O(n log max(A))`.

Comment: "we could check for each element, the minimum number of times it requires to apply x operations".  What is `x`?

Comment: @Bernard  In the problem statement `...we can choose one of the elements in the array, A[i] and reduce it by a fixed amount X`, sorry for the confusion

Comment: "the minimum number of times it requires to minus x within a operations". Hmm. What is your strategy for determining the minimum number of times? Don't forget that we have to factor in the other value, Y as well.

Comment: @LanceHAOH either you can use binary search, find min `b`, so that `b*X + (mid - b)*Y >= A[i]`; or solve that math equation.

Comment: @PhamTrung +1 I am convinced. This solution should work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @PhamTrung I have a sudden thought. We need to ensure that the min value of b that we calculate for each element must be consistent with the rest of the elements. i.e. We have mid - b = a where b is the number of times we apply Y on an array element. But b0 has to fulfill the equation b0 = a1 + a2 + a3 + ... + an where bi is the number of times we apply Y on the ith element of the array and ai is the number of times we apply X on the ith element of the array. How does your solution ensure that?

Comment: @LanceHAOH you only need to make sure `b0 + b1 + b2.. + bn` <= `mid`, because we only interested in minimum case. If `b0 + b1 + b2 + .. + bn < mid`, we can just add more into those elements without harming the result.

Comment: Accepted! Thanks so much for your help!